# How should I report bugs in my Bq Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

On the desktop ubuntu-bug tool should be used, but what's the correct procedure to report Ubuntu Phone bugs?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to myself. Information about bug reporting on Ubuntu Touch can be found in here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers